# C# parallelize loop

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I have the following c# code:

```
        int[] ns = new int[4] { 100, 500, 1000, 5000 };
        int[] ks = new int[5] { 5, 10, 15, 80, 160 };
        int[] rs = new int[10] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        for(int n = 0; n<ns.Length; n++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < ks.Length; k++)
            {
                for (int r = 0; r < rs.Length; r++)
                {
                    RunProg(ns[n], ks[k], rs[r]);
                }
            }
        }
```

where `RunProg` takes a relatively substantial amount of time. I would like to parallelize this code. What is the most straight forward way to parallelize this in C#?

I have not tried any method yet. I was trying to decide between the different [functionalities available in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/data-parallelism-task-parallel-library)

Comment: Is RunProg safe to call concurrently? we can't tell you the most straightforward way without knowing that information. Also, what have you tried so far to do it and what did not work about it?

Comment: Why is everyone marking this question as "too broad"? Doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: `RunProg` can safely be run concurrently yes.

Comment: @bdeonovic A simple way to parallelize this is to replace your loop(s) with a computed sequence of `Task`s which run on the thread pool, and which you aggregate into a result using `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin, it's a typical "what have you tried" close reason. *"I would like to parallelize this code"* - and? What happen then? The world crashes or google starts saying 404? *"I was trying to decide"* - here comes your *broad* part.

Comment: The user is asking how to parallelize a sequential loop, which is a totally on-topic question for a site about programming. There is a reason there is no "low effort" close reason anymore. If you think it is an extremely simple question that people keep asking all the time, mark it as a duplicate of a reference question/answer that explains the answer.

Comment: @Sinatr thanks for the pointers. I'm really just trying to figure out "what even is the question I want to ask" because when I look up parallelism for C# I am getting lots of different ways to do it.

Comment: @bdeonovic So of those many ways that you looked up on how to solve the problem, which of them worked, and which of them didn't work.  For those that didn't work, what, specifically, didn't work about them?

Comment: One way would be to just parallelize the inner loop, or what ever loop has a greater number of items to process. Since we don't want to parallelize stuff just because, we always want to pick out the item that will have the most impact. There is always a tradeoff, but I would give the inner loop a shot. Convert arrays to a list, and then use LINQ Parallel.ForEach. It would at the very least reduce your run time a bit. Work backwards from there and I am sure you'll be able to nail it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to parallelize this is to produce a sequence representing all combinations of inputs, then transforming this sequence to a sequence of thread pool tasks representing the result. This final sequence can simply be passed to `Task.WhenAll` to await the completion of all tasks.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] ns = new int[4] { 100, 500, 1000, 5000 };
        int[] ks = new int[5] { 5, 10, 15, 80, 160 };
        int[] rs = new int[10] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        var inputs = ns
            .SelectMany(n => ks.Select(k => new { n, k }))
            .SelectMany(x => rs.Select(r => new { x.n, x.k, r }));

        var tasks = inputs.Select(x => Task.Run(() => RunProg(x.n, x.k, x.r)));
        var results = Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result;
    }

    static int RunProg(int n, int k, int r)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return n + k + r;
    }
}
```

You can also `Parallel.ForEach` over the `inputs` collection, as mentioned in the other answers.

```
Parallel.ForEach(inputs, x => RunProg(x.n, x.k, x.r));
```

Comment: Except if you have thousands items in your array - that will start thousands of threads and put whole process to the knees.

Comment: @Evk How many threads are started is dictated by the thread pool AFAIK, it is not unbounded.

Comment: Well that's true but still, usually you want to limit number of parallel computations in such cases.

Comment: @Evk It's already limited, the thread pool limits the number of computations. If you want custom control over concurrency you can pass a custom scheduler.

Comment: Default number of max threads in thread pool is very high (on last .NET versions at least), tens of thousands. So limitation comes only from the fact new threads are added with a delay (of something like 0.5 seconds as I remember). But that means you are starving global resource (thread pool), because any other code which uses thread pool will also wait for 0.5 seconds to start new thread while your code is running. That's of course assuming `RunProg` runs for quite a long time. All in all I'd prefer `Parallel.ForEach`.

Comment: This is the kind of discussion I was looking for. Thanks guys!! I ended up going with Parallel.ForEach with the sequence created by @AsadSaeeduddin

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Parallel.For](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop) method:

```
int[] ns = new int[4] { 100, 500, 1000, 5000 };
int[] ks = new int[5] { 5, 10, 15, 80, 160 };
int[] rs = new int[10] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
Parallel.For(0, ns.Length, n =>
{
    Parallel.For(0, ks.Length, k =>
    {
        Parallel.For(0, rs.Length, r =>
        {
            RunProg(ns[n], ks[k], rs[r]);
        });
    });
});
```

This should work provided that the order in which the `RunProg` method is called is not important, and that the method itself is thread-safe.

Comment: Isn't it better to first produce list of all combinations in 3 arrays and then run `Parallel.For` over that (instead of 3 `Parallel.For`)?

Comment: The partitioning in this example will be wonky, you should use a single `Parallel.For` after constructing a single sequence of work inputs.

Comment: "Isn't it better...". Not if the order doesn't matter. First producing all combinations means that you will end up with more iterations in total. The code in my answer runs the RunProg method 4 *5 * 10 = 200 times as expected, once for each combination of n,k and r.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Parallel.For()` for the loops: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx

This works if the iterations are not dependent on each other.

Comment: Why only inner loop? What if `rs` array contains just 1 element and `ns` and ` ks` contain thousand each?